# Ajax call not hitting the function of asp.net web form page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

Here is jquery ajax call function

```
    function Press() {           
        var number = $("#num").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetStuffList",
            data: "{ num:' + number + ' }",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger
                alert("Test")
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is my webforms page function

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetStuffList(string num)
    {

        return num;
    }
```

Question:

That jquery function  is successfully hit but ajax call is not hitting webform page function.

Comment: Have you `console.log(response)` to check what page it is hitting, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should comment out one line in App_Code/RouteConfig.cs

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

should be

```
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Also your ajax post has an issue in data and you should use JSON response:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetStuffList",
            data: '{num: "' + number + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);                
            }
        });
```

Cheers,